# File size restriction upon form submission

Tags: spring-boot

Is both approaches the same when it comes to application processing the request?

- `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size`
- Or just validating the file in my controller (or using form validation using @Valid and implementing Validator, etc).

Does both approaches check file size AFTER application has fully received the request? Or `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` sets the file upload size restriction at the server (tomcat) level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` is a better approach. This property is set for MultipartResolver bean automatically. This bean is created automatically in Springboot. In Spring and/or Spring MVC (basically, not Springboot), this bean needs to be created manually.

MultipartResolver bean is the one that handles the file size uploaded via a form. This approach is better because it doesn't load up the whole file. It gets the file size through a header, and if file size exceeds the value set as a value for the property `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size`, it throws an error.

Validating the file size via @Valid/Validator approach is not wise because the whole file will be uploaded to the server.